# Heroku CLI doesn't see static files of Flask application

Tags: flask, heroku, web-deployment

I build and deployed to Heroku small blogging application in Flask. I am saving static images such as user avatars and post images under the static/profile_pics and static/post_image folders. In my local development environment, it works as expected. But when I am using my deployed application on Heroku. I tried to investigate those files with the following command:

```sh
$ heroku login
$ heroku run bash -a my_application_name
$ cd app
```

Here I found my project files, but I was not able to find my uploaded avatar image and post image under the static/profile_pics and static/post_image folders. What is strange, that application works as expected, but I can not see my uploaded files via Heroku CLI using ls command. When accessing my application I can see the correct web address of my static images in the browser address bar, but can not see it with ls command in Heroku CLI. Could someone explain to me, what is going on? Thanks a lot.
[image]

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Comment: Thanks a lot. What is the best practise to store such static files? Should I use some external resources such as Amazon S3?

Comment: I haven't done this myself so I can't give you any recommendation. Amazon S3 is something I heard people do many times. You can also rent a VPS for 5$ a month or even lower and host your scripts there as normal

Comment: solved my problem by using whitenoise that provides simplified static file serving for Python web apps: https://pypi.org/project/whitenoise/